# Is there a word for someone who enforces rules using a double standard because of some bias?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example would be an officer choosing to give person A a speeding ticket and choosing to not give person B a speeding ticket, even if both persons were speeding in identical situations on different instances. Person A might be a different race or gender to person B, for instance, or the officer might have had some other bias.

Another would be say, a park has a sign up that says "no pets on grass" which goes ignored regularly by many people. A citizen might choose to oppose a particular person for breaking said rule while choosing to ignore it for others. The underlying reason is that the citizen simply doesn't like the person they are confronting because of some bias, and projecting that through "being right" about some rule.

Comment: Have you checked the synonyms for [prejudiced](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/prejudiced)?

Comment: @HotLicks I would like the word to have some association with selective rule enforcement rather than a more broad "biased" or "prejudiced".

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: How is this different from the scores of similar questions on our site?

Comment: @tchrist Can you link one of those questions? I'm not seeing one that is the same.

Comment: Go to town:
[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-requests%5D+is%3Aa+prejudiced)
[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-requests%5D+is%3Aa+biased)
[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-requests%5D+is%3Aa+bigoted)
[4](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-requests%5D+is%3Aa+unfair)
[5](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-requests%5D+is%3Aa+partisan)
[6](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-requests%5D+is%3Aa+sectarian)

Comment: @tchrist They do not have to do with selective rule enforcement. I understand English can be subtle.

Comment: Then good enough, and thank you for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call them **"partial"**, as opposed to "impartial".

> - "Inclined to favor one party more than the other" [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partial)

> - "Favoring one person or side over another or others: a decision that was partial to the plaintiff." [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/partial)

Comment: Interesting. I do think "partial" has a connotation with law (at least in my mind), with usage like "partial juror", "partial judge", etc.